# Querying empty Datamapper has n relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datamapper

In my Rails app I have two models: Briefing and Company. Briefing has n, :companies, :through => Resource and Company has n, :briefings, :through => Resource.

I'm trying to find all the briefings that have don't have any companies associated with them. As incorrect code this might look something like:

```
Briefing.all( :companies => nil )
```

or

```
Briefing.all( :companies.eql => [] )
```

but of course those don't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Not quite the same - that one has a has n, belongs_to relationship in which case searching on the empty id column in the belongs_to class is trivial. In my case it's two has n relationships through Resource, which means no id column in either model.

Comment: I think there may be a bug with this type of match and m:m associations. It should work on the 1:m intermediary associations though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Dan just [pushed a change](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core/commit/bfc0f8339fe88eadc11e2d0e7595147058e250d8) that makes possible to run such a query. So if you have a User.has n, :posts and you run a query like that:

```
User.all(:posts => nil)
```

Then the generated SQL will look like that:

```
SELECT "id" FROM "users" WHERE NOT("id" IN (SELECT "user_id" FROM "posts")) ORDER BY "id"
```

This will be available in DataMapper 1.1.1

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it's the same thing. That commit was more for gte/gt/lte/lt type matches where someone used nil as the value to match against. And it really only affected in-memory matching too.